# Parameters of energy function for TSP

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, np

I am reading [this paper](http://www.genomics.princeton.edu/hopfield/PDFs/TSP.pdf) by Hopfield et al. On page six, the authors defined the energy function of the Traveling-Salesman-Problem (TSP) mapped onto an artificial neural network as follows:

$$E = \frac{A}{2} \sum_X \sum_i \sum_{j \ne i} V_{Xi} V_{Xj} + \frac{B}{2} \sum_i \sum_X \sum_{X\ne Y} V_{Xi} V_{Yi} + \frac{C}{2} (\sum_X \sum_i V_{Xi} - n)^2 + \frac{1}{2D} \sum_X \sum_{Y\ne X} \sum_i d_{XY} V_{Xi} (V_{Y, i+1} + V_{Y, i-1})$$

Here the first three terms maintain correctness of the function while the final term calculate actual distance of the tour. Later on page seven, the authors picked the values of A, B, C and D for simulation.

I don't understand on what basis they choose those values. Any help?

Comment: Anyone with any help?